# Import Excel Sheet to SQL Server, skip primary key violations

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, ssis

I would like to import an excel file to table in SQL server.  The table has 3 or 4 columns that combine to make a primary key.  I want to be able to run the import at any time, and if ever there is a conflict with the primary key, just simply don't import that row, but continue to import all the other rows.

I created a *.dtsx file, which does the import fine, but dies the moment it finds a duplicate key. Is there a way to tell the *.dtsx file to continue if it finds a duplicate, and not just die?  I tried opening the *.dtsx file, but there aren't many options, when i right click the *.dtsx file and choose edit, Visual Studio opens up and appears to show me some way of editing the *.dtsx file, but i'm not familiar with it at all.  Any guidance is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a "check constraint" check box on the OleDBDestination Component that it is used to ignore the contraints like PK, but I dont think it will solve your problem.

The ideal thing to do is between your source and destination component, you add a lookup component to check if the row already exist on the DB and only insert if it doesnt exist.

I know you said that you dont know SSIS but this is the approach you probably will have to take. It isnt difficult at all to create\edit a simple package like this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155804/ssis-performing-a-lookup-on-another-table-to-get-related-column) is an example on the forum

Comment: Thanks @Diego, you're right, the SSIS -> Lookup Component turned out to be just right.  They have a power feature there that gives 2 outputs: matched records, and unmatched records.  All I had to do was configure that a little and stream the unmatched records to my destination.  Quiet easy, thanks for your help!