# using ssis to move tabels and parts of tables from one database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis

I am currently using a database that is poorly designed and a slow pipeline so i decided to copy a small portion of the database (15 tables) and only bring over some of those tables for example i want to bring only the rows that have a certain id.
But this is not a one time move i need to add all the stuff that is added to the old database added to the new one on an hourly basis. My research has led me to SSIS and that it may have a way of accomplishing this but i have found no clear examples on how it is done if in fact it is possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible . You can schedule your ssis package through sql agent to run on hourly basis .

For a table ,you can drag a Data Flow Task  on to the control flow .Inside DFT ,you need to place an oledb Source component ,Lookup ,Data conversion (if the types are different in source and target table) and Oledb destination .

`oledb Source component` :  Create a variable of type string and in the expression write your sql query to fetch the data based on ID.Now use this variable in source component.

`Lookup`: You need to select your source table and combine the primary key column from the source and destination table.It acts similar to inner join query .After combining the primary key from the both the tables ,select the columns which you need from the source .

`Oledb destination` : Simply select your target table and map the columns from `Lookup no matched output` .If you need to update the values from the source then use `Lookup matched output` and connect it to an execute SQL task and write the update query .

Please go thru the [link](http://www.julian-kuiters.id.au/article.php/ssis-lookup-with-range) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155804/ssis-performing-a-lookup-on-another-table-to-get-related-column)
[Scheduling of SSIS package](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/scheduling-ssis-packages-with-sql-server-agent/)

Comment: do i have to create a new OLE DB Source for each table?

Comment: Yes if the table structure are different then you need to create seperate oledb source