# Search for a value of a source in to another source

Tags: ssis

I am new to ssis. I am actually having a ole db source and a flat file source. I want to look for each value of the specific column of the flat file in to ole db source. If match then get that perticuler row or (2 columns value of that row).

Earlier i was thinking that i can do it with Lookup but i am confused how to send the search key in to Lookup from flat file source.

Or can you suggest me another way around.?

Comment: Lookup should work but you can also use Merge Join.

Comment: Which version of SSIS? 2012?

Comment: @Jayvee I think so merge join can work and lookup as well but. What my case is that i have a column which contains a value acording to that i want to saerch for a key value in the another source. So if i will merge them how should i o or for lookup..?

Comment: you can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155804/ssis-performing-a-lookup-on-another-table-to-get-related-column

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Actually my concepts were not clear about merge join.
It worked using merge join