# SSIS - Loop through multiple data source data

Tags: ssis

Im very new to SSIS. I have the following scenario
I receive a dataset from SourceA through a Execute SQL task -each row has 3 columns - ColumnA,Column b,Column C

I have a second data source(source 3) which would return Column D for each column C in previous dataset.

Once I recieve this data, I need to map/store Column A and Column D to be stored into out local DB(Source 3).

Can you give me a high level idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155804/ssis-performing-a-lookup-on-another-table-to-get-related-column

Answer (score 0):

Use the MERGE JOIN transformation object.

[image]

The MERGE JOIN transformation object is the SSIS equivalent of the SQL `JOIN` syntax.  Two datasets in, one dataset out.  One requirement of using the SSIS merge join is that the incoming datasets must be sorted on the columns which will be doing the join.  In your case, this means sorting column C from the left-side datasource and column D from the right-side datasource.

Once you have sorted datasets, drag-and-drop the merge join tool and connect them to the merge join object.  Edit the merge join object and select "left outer join." Drag column C over to column D to create the join.  Then uncheck column B and column C to remove them from the output.  The result will be a dataset that has columns A and D, joined upon column C.  For a more detailed example, look [here](http://letslearnssis.blogspot.com/2011/07/merge-merge-join-and-union-all.html). Hope that helps!